# Markdown table not recognised in MS Teams Chat

Tags: markdown, microsoft-teams

There is an issue where Markdown Table is not getting recognized in MS Teams it comes as it is in the MS Teams Chat. The Microsoft Custom Question Answering the code is as given below in the image

[image]

But when it renders onto the MS Teams from the KB, the syntax remains as it in MS Teams Chat

[image]

Please any inputs on handling the Markdown Table syntax to work in MS Teams. It works fine in webchat and KB chat, but in MS Teams it gets rendered as it is.

Are there any ways or workaround to handle the same. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teams doesn't support the full markdown syntax options, just a small subset - see here for the list: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-markdown-formatting-in-teams-4d10bd65-55e2-4b2d-a1f3-2bebdcd2c772#ID0EBBD=Desktop

If you want to render a table, you'd be better off using an adaptive card. Here's an example of a table: https://adaptivecards.io/samples/WeatherLarge.html . You'd need to check whether the Question Answering endpoint returns a "table" syntax, and send back an adaptive card instead of a regular text response. See here a starting point, if you've not used Cards before: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/getting-started/bots

Comment: Thanks this helps, have used the Adaptive cards before, need to check how to identify answers with a table syntax and build build a table in Adatpive cards.